# Change Jtable a cell value and replace old string with new cell value to text file

Tags: java, netbeans, jtable, text-files

I can update the status when the row is selected in JTable but I cant update the status in text file. How can I update the status of an order in the text file when the status is being update in JTable at the same time?

order2.txt

```
Order Id , Status,      Food,     Food Quantity,    Drinks,    Drinks Quantity
1       Preparing       Fried Chicken       2       Sprite      2
2       Preparing       Fried Chicken       2       Coke        2
3       Preparing       Fried Chicken       2       Coke        2
```

Code

```
   private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        int selectedRow = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
        statusTextField.setText(model.getValueAt(selectedRow,1).toString());
    }        



  private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        int i = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
        
        if (i >= 0){
            model.setValueAt(statusTextField.getText(),i,1);
            tml(i);
        }
    }     

  private void jCheckBox2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        statusTextField.setText("Ready To Serve");
    }
```

JTable image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xB1nG.png)

Table listener

```
private void tml(int i) {
         // Generated from nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Classes/Code/GeneratedMethodBody
    }

   

    private abstract class tml implements TableModelListener  {

    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
    private Object[] columnNames;
    private Object[][] rowData;
    
    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columnNames[col].toString();
    }
    public int getRowCount() { return rowData.length; }
    public int getColumnCount() { return columnNames.length; }
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        return rowData[row][col];
    }
     public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col)
        { return true; }
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
        rowData[row][col] = value;
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
    }

        private void fireTableCellUpdated(int row, int col) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); // Generated from nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Classes/Code/GeneratedMethodBody
        }
    }
```

Comment: Add a `TableModelListener` to the `TableModel`. Any time data is changed an event will be generated. Then you rewrite all the data from the model to the file.

Comment: @camickr im new to java so is it possible for u to show me how  to do it?

Comment: Do what? I'm not sure what you find confusing. We are not here to write the application for you. We can give you  pointers on specific problems. You learn by trying. Search the site for examples that use a TableModelListener (if this is what your confusion is about). Write some code. If it doesn't work then you post your [mre] showing what you have tried.

Comment: @camickr I tried adding ```TableModelListener ```  but still cant work. I know im still missing something but i dont know what is it.

Comment: Why are you implementing TableModel methods? Where do you implement any of the `TableModelListener` methods? Read the API. Search the site for working examples. I can't help if you don't post a proper [mre].